# Helper function throwing error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
let storage = {};

storage.saveCredentials = (token:any, id:any) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('userId', id);
}

storage.saveStatus = (status:any) => {
    localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(status));
}


export default storage;
```

I get the error that `Property 'saveCredentials' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Comment: I mean to say TypeSCript not Javascript.

Comment: Why _do_ you define an empty object then try to add properties to it? You could provide a type for the object, but to allow the initial empty value the properties would all have to be optional then that spreads out over the rest of the codebase. Why not define it with the methods in one go, or just have two named-export-ed functions, and/or `export default { saveCredentials, saveStatus };` where the inferred type is what you actually want.

Comment: just add any interface to your storage variable `let storage: any = {};
`

Comment: @Indraraj26 then all of your consumers become unsafely-typed too, bad idea. At that point why even use TS?

Comment: Totally agree with @jonrsharpe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree with you. I though he is new to TS.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript determines the type of `storage` at declaration, so storage has just the type of an empty object without any members.
You should add the functions directly when you create the object:

```
const storage = {
    saveCredentials: (token:any, id:any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('userId', id);
    },
    saveStatus: (status:any) => {
         localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(status));
    }
}

export default storage;
```

If you want to add members dynamically at runtime, declare storage as any:

```
let storage: any = {}
```

But you will loose the type safety then.

Comment: Why using `let` if this is only declared once and the reference is not changing? You should  use `const` instead to declare storage. Also, as @jonrsharpe pointed out, it's better to create and use an interface than useing the type `any`

Answer (score -1):

It is better to create function and export it.

```
const saveCredentials = (token: any, id: any) => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  localStorage.setItem('userId', id);
};

const saveStatus = (status: any) => {
  localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(status));
};

export { saveCredentials, saveStatus };
```

use it like this

```
import { saveCredentials, saveStatus } from './storage';
```

Comment: And now you have to guard against the methods not being there all over the rest of your codebase, even though they always will be.

Comment: I updated the code and added better way to deal with it.